# How do you specify pandas groupby operations that operate on previous records?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe as following which has to be sorted by Col_2:

```
+----+-------+-------+ 
| id | Col_1 | Col_2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |     0 |    21 |
|  1 |     1 |    24 |
|  1 |     1 |    32 |
|  1 |     0 |    35 |
|  1 |     1 |    37 |
|  2 |     0 |     2 |
|  2 |     0 |     5 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

How can I create two new columns:

Col_1_sum: the sum of values in the previous rows for each id.
Col_2_max: the max value of Col_2 in the last rows which Col_1 was one. (for each id)

For example for above dataframe the result should be:

```
+----+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+
| id | Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_1_Sum | Col_2_Max |
+----+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |     0 |    21 |         0 |         0 |
|  1 |     1 |    24 |         0 |         0 |
|  1 |     1 |    32 |         1 |        24 |
|  1 |     0 |    35 |         2 |        32 |
|  1 |     1 |    37 |         2 |        32 |
|  2 |     0 |     2 |         0 |         0 |
|  2 |     0 |     5 |         0 |         0 |
+----+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two questions. One at a time.

Your first question is answered with `groupby`, `shift`, and `cumsum`:

```
df.groupby('id').Col_1.apply(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum())

0    NaN
1    0.0
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    2.0
5    NaN
6    0.0
Name: Col_1, dtype: float64
```

Or, if you prefer cleaner output,

```
df.groupby('id').Col_1.apply(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum()).fillna(0).astype(int)

0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    0
6    0
Name: Col_1, dtype: int64
```

Your second, also similar, using `groupby`, `shift`, `cummax` and `ffill`:

```
df.Col_2.where(df.Col_1.eq(1)).groupby(df.id).apply(
    lambda x: x.shift().cummax().ffill()
)

0     NaN
1     NaN
2    24.0
3    32.0
4    32.0
5     NaN
6     NaN
Name: Col_2, dtype: float64
```

In both cases, the essential ingredient is a `groupby` followed by a subsequent shift call. Note that these answers are difficult to solve sans `apply` because there are multiple operations to be carried out on sub-groups.

Consider taking the lambda out by defining a custom function. You'll save a few cycles on larger data.